# Is this a standard representation of a 'space' character?

Tags: strings, notation

I recently came across a handwritten note with directions to push a string of text into a database. There was a strange character in the string I've never seen before, **a lower case 'b' with a forward slash through it:**

[image: b with a slash through it]

I asked the author about it and he said it was an old-school way of representing a space.

My question is whether or not this was a standard/widely used representation of a space character and if so, whether or not it's still commonly used.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - I get where you're coming from on that. What I'm after is the context in which it was originally used and whether it still has a use today. Hopefully that's clear by the question.

Comment: @TheIronCheek Given the answer, it seems I was being overly pessimistic/skeptical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbol ␢ has a unicode representation: [2422-unicode-blank-symbol](http://www.charbase.com/2422-unicode-blank-symbol).

It is an old typographic symbol for specifying explicit blanks in code.
As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#File_names) states:

> This was used in the early years of computer programming when writing
>   on coding forms. Keypunch operators immediately recognized the symbol
>   as an 'explicit space'.

ps. I also learned this symbol as Turing tape blank. I will check an old book later. Nowadays I would use B or if I am feeling adventurous ␣ 'open box' (U+2423) $\text{\textvisiblespace}$.

Comment: So this question is offtopic?

Comment: @Raphael  We have had questions on origins of notation before.

Comment: Notation, sure. Programming syntax, borderline.